# Using Javascript to add HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if it was possible to get Javascript to write some HTML onto the page in a certain DIV.

This is due to the fact, there are certain areas of the site where i don't have access to the markup. But i would like to add a small section there.

For example the container i want to add some html to is 
<*div id="topics"><*/div>

Is it possible to get Javascript to do this 
<*div id="topics"> <*div id="mysection"> <*/div> <*/div>

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fairly simple to do, even using plain JavaScript.

```
var topicsDiv = document.getElementById("topics");
topicsDiv.innerHTML = '<div id="mysection"> </div>';
```

If you're going to be doing some serious DOM (Document Object Model, i.e. HTML structure) manipulation, however, then I would recommend you look into using the [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) library. Yet if the task is limited to your question, then normal JavaScript should be fine, as shown above.

Comment: innerHTML has "HTML" capitalised, and don't forget to escape your double quotes!

Comment: @Perspx: Or just use single quotes. :)

Answer (score 5):

With simple Javascript (without JQuery or something you could do):

HTML:

```
<div id="topics"></div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('topics').innerHTML = '<div id="mysection"></div>';
```

Using JQuery you would simply do:

```
$('#topics').append('<div id="mysection"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course. For example, you can do this using [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/):

```
$('topics').update('<div id="mysection"></div>');
```

The syntax is quite similar for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or another frameworks, and as Noldorin noted, you can do also this without any framework.

Comment: Bump on the use of Prototype.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the innerHTML property

```
document.getElementById('topics').innerHTML = 'whatever';
```

Comment: Just to be pedantic, innerHTML is a property, not a function.

Comment: I took the liberty of making that fix.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with both *Noldorin* and *Can Berk Güder* and others, and I'd like to quote that this is DOM (Document Object Model) and one of the main components of AJAX.
AJAX send a request to a server, and uses techniques such as this to "put it" in the page.

Know that you can do almost anything with javascript; you could just have "<html><body></body></html>" and have javascript do ALL the rest. This is what [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) does, and if you need to HEAVILY modify you page dynamically, you may be interested in it.